# Java performance avoid creating new in loop

Tags: java, performance, list

I have a code like this

```
Map<String, List> searchMap = new HashMap<String, List>();
for(int i=0; i<something.size(); i++){
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list = getResult(...);
 ...
 searchMap.put(differentkey, list);
}
```

Each time I am creating new List in loop. How to avoid creating new list in loop.

Comment: We can't tell from your code what you're doing (what is i for? What is `getResult`?). It is only clear, that `= new ArrayList<String> ();\n list` can be ommited, since list get's then bound to `getResult (...);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply don't create the List at all since it is not even used in the code you have shown.

```
List<String> list = getResult(...);
```

Comment: Will it not its taking reference of list in map. When I try to return or iterate over map. It may have different result in it.

Comment: Also, make sure `ArrayList` is the appropriate type of list to create. It might be that creating a `LinkedList`, for example, would be more efficient. I wonder if random access to this `List` is really needed?

Comment: @imrantariq: We don't know what `getResult()` does, which makes it harder to understand what's going on. If this code doesn't work, you need to give us more information - because it *should*. Of course, if you need to pass a list into `getResult()` then that confuses things slightly - but you need to give us that information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

Why would you *want* to? It looks like you want as many lists as you have keys, given that your map is from a key to a list... so you want that many distinct lists.

In particular, you *don't* want to just clear the list on each iteration - as otherwise each map entry will refer to the *same list*.

Now you don't have to create an *empty* list which you then ignore - you can assign the value of `getResult()` immediately to the variable, in the declaration:

```
List<String> list = getResult(...);
```

That's likely to still be creating a new list on each iteration (unless `getResult()` returns an existing one) but that's probably what you want anyway.

Note that there's no benefit in declaring the `list` variable *outside* the loop - the variable declaration doesn't affect performance, but it's generally a good idea to limit a variable's scope as much as possible - so I'd keep the declaration where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Map<String, List> searchMap = new HashMap<String, List>();
for(int i=0; i<something.size(); i++){
    List<String> list = getResult(...);
    ...
    searchMap.put(differentkey, list);
}
```

There's no need to construct a new list.

Comment: Curse you and your 12 second advantage!

Comment: @Paul Hah! Beat you for fourth place. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List> searchMap = new HashMap<String, List>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<something.size(); i++){
    list = getResult(...);
    ...
    searchMap.put(differentkey, list);
}
```

On the 4th line (`list = getResult(...);`) you're assigning a new object to your `list`variable. So there's no need to create new list before that. Your variable will be replaced anyway.

Comment: Why does he need to construct a new `ArrayList` at all?

Comment: And why would he want to widen the scope of the list variable?

Comment: Maybe he uses that after 4th line. We don't know what he means under "..." (5th line)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<something.size(); i++){
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list = getResult(...);
```

is equivalent to

```
for(int i=0; i<something.size(); i++){
 List<String> list = getResult(...);
```

But I'm not sure, whether you're really searching for this.